# How can I wrap a transaction around Membership.CreateUser?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership

I'm using the asp.net SqlMembershipProvider and LinqToSql in a hobby/learning application. I have some user properties that I'm keeping in LinqtoSql, so my flow is:
Membership.CreateUser -> MyClass.AddUserDetails. I'd like to wrap the whole thing in a transaction, so if the myclass bit fails I can roll back the membership bit. Any suggestions on how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The providers don't explicitly support transactions, I asked for this feature some time ago:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=102268

I think if you use the TransactionScope class it should work, though you will have the overhead of an MSDTC-coordinated transaction.

Comment: And the headaches of DTC. Getting it to work in a shared environment for example... sob...

Answer (score 4):

My real life experience (happened more than once):

- Junior programmer writes a site.
- During code review, I catch the missing transaction between user creation and profile creation (typically with a custom SqlProvider)
- We wrap everything in a DTC transaction.
- Nothing works on junior programmer's computer.
- Fix DTC on junior programmer's computer.
- Deploy to shared hosting environment.
- Nothing works in hosting environment.
- Argue for 4 hours with hosting company trying to fix their DTC.
- Remove transaction because site *has* to go online.
- Pray.

I don't really like membership anymore...

Comment: Same experience here, minus the hosting part.  Although I'm not sure why TransactionScope always wants to require DTC, when it shouldn't need it.... at least when Membership is involved.

Comment: Is this still the state-of-the-art as far as you know: i.e. do you still use Membership and without transactions, or have you found any better alternative?

Comment: @ChrisW afaik nobody really uses membership anymore

Comment: Thanks. I guess people use the new ASP 'Identity' system (or something like that?) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Transaction property of the DataContext to make it participate in a transaction you already have.